# twisted portforward proxy send back data to client

Tags: python, proxy, twisted

Here is some code I have come up with so far...

```
   from twisted.internet import protocol,reactor
   from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol,ClientFactory

   class serverprotocol(Protocol):

       def dataReceived(self,data):
            print "[+] got \n" + data
            factory = protocol.ClientFactory()
            factory.protocol = Clientp
            global xx
            xx=data
            print xx
            reactor.connectTCP("127.0.0.1",80,factory)

   class Clientp(Protocol):
       def connectionMade(self):
            print "sending " + xx
            self.transport.write(xx)

       def dataReceived(self,data):
            print "+ got reply" + data

   factory = protocol.ServerFactory()
   factory.protocol = serverprotocol
   reactor.listenTCP(3333, factory)
   reactor.run()
```

I am wondering how I can send the data received in the client class back the client that 
connects on port 3333.

If there is a better way to code this please do let Me know.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Twisted FAQ: ["How do I make input on one connection result in output on another"?](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#HowdoImakeinputononeconnectionresultinoutputonanother)

But it's not really a Twisted question.  It's more of a basic Python programming question.

What you're asking is, given the class `Clientp`, how do you pass an argument to it so that it knows what to do later?

The answer is very simply "give it an `__init__`, pass it an argument"

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory
from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ClientEndpoint
from twisted.internet import reactor

class serverprotocol(Protocol):

    def dataReceived(self,data):
        print "[+] got \n" + data
        def clientProtocol():
            return Clientp(data)
        endpoint = TCP4ClientEndpoint(reactor, "127.0.0.1", 80)
        endpoint.connect(Factory.forProtocol(clientProtocol))

class Clientp(Protocol):
    def __init__(self, dataToSend):
        self.dataToSend = dataToSend

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.transport.write(self.dataToSend)

    def dataReceived(self,data):
        print "+ got reply" + data

reactor.listenTCP(3333,
                  Factory.forProtocol(serverprotocol))
reactor.run()
```

If what you want is a full port forwarder, you could instead simply use `twistd portforward` or look at the code in [`twisted.protocols.portforward`](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/trunk/twisted/protocols/portforward.py).

Answer (score 0):

```
from twisted.internet import protocol,reactor
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol,ClientFactory

clients=[]

class serverprotocol(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        g.append(self)

    def dataReceived(self,data):

        factory = protocol.ClientFactory()
        factory.protocol = Clientp
        global xx
        xx=data
        reactor.connectTCP("127.0.0.1",80,factory)

class Clientp(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        print "sending "
        self.transport.write(xx)

    def dataReceived(self,data):
        print "+ got reply"

        for x in clients:
          x.transport.write(data)

factory = protocol.ServerFactory()
factory.protocol = serverprotocol
reactor.listenTCP(8080, factory)
reactor.run()
```

Comment: If there is a better python way to do this please let Me know..That is basically a port-forwarding proxy..

Answer (score -1):

Because I'm biased I'm going to present a non-Twisted solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from uuid import uuid4 as uuid

from circuits import Component
from circuits.net.events import close, connect, write
from circuits.net.sockets import TCPClient, TCPServer


class Client(Component):

    channel = "client"

    def init(self, sock, host, port, channel=channel):
        self.sock = sock
        self.host = host
        self.port = port

        TCPClient(channel=self.channel).register(self)

    def ready(self, *args):
        self.fire(connect(self.host, self.port))

    def disconnect(self, *args):
        self.fire(close(self.sock), self.parent.channel)

    def read(self, data):
        self.fire(write(self.sock, data), self.parent.channel)


class Proxy(Component):

    channel = "server"

    def init(self, bind, host, port):
        self.bind = bind
        self.host = host
        self.port = port

        self.clients = dict()

        TCPServer(self.bind).register(self)

    def connect(self, sock, host, port):
        channel = uuid()

        client = Client(
            sock, self.host, self.port, channel=channel
        ).register(self)

        self.clients[sock] = client

    def disconnect(self, sock):
        client = self.clients.get(sock)
        if client is not None:
            client.unregister()
            del self.clients[sock]

    def read(self, sock, data):
        client = self.clients[sock]
        self.fire(write(data), client.channel)


app = Proxy(("0.0.0.0", 3333), "127.0.0.1", 22)

from circuits import Debugger
Debugger().register(app)

app.run()
```

This works as expected as a full tcp port forwarding proxy using the [circuits](http://circuits.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) framework.

Here's an example run:

**Terminal 1 (server):**

```
Fri May 23 14:05:02
~/circuits
$ ./proxy.py
<registered[server] (<TCPServer/server 48541:MainThread (queued=0) [S]>, <Proxy/server 48541:MainThread (queued=3) [R]> )>
<registered[*] (<Debugger/* 48541:MainThread (queued=0) [S]>, <Proxy/server 48541:MainThread (queued=4) [R]> )>
<started[server] (<Proxy/server 48541:MainThread (queued=3) [R]> )>
<registered[select] (<Select/select 48541:MainThread (queued=0) [S]>, <TCPServer/server 48541:MainThread (queued=0) [S]> )>
<ready[server] (<TCPServer/server 48541:MainThread (queued=0) [S]>, ('0.0.0.0', 3333) )>
<_read[server] (<socket._socketobject object at 0x100ff57c0> )>
<connect[server] (<socket._socketobject object at 0x100ff5980>, '127.0.0.1', 52911 )>
<_read[server] (<socket._socketobject object at 0x100ff5980> )>
<registered[ee1c155f-d2de-4f09-b05d-5b5e6f4de1d6] (<TCPClient/ee1c155f-d2de-4f09-b05d-5b5e6f4de1d6 48541:MainThread (queued=0) [S]>, <Client/ee1c155f-d2de-4f09-b05d-5b5e6f4de1d6 48541:MainThread (queued=0) [S]> )>
<registered[ee1c155f-d2de-4f09-b05d-5b5e6f4de1d6] (<Client/ee1c155f-d2de-4f09-b05d-5b5e6f4de1d6 48541:MainThread (queued=0) [S]>, <Proxy/server 48541:MainThread (queued=3) [R]> )>
<read[server] (<socket._socketobject object at 0x100ff5980>, 'SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2\r\n' )>
<ready[ee1c155f-d2de-4f09-b05d-5b5e6f4de1d6] (<TCPClient/ee1c155f-d2de-4f09-b05d-5b5e6f4de1d6 48541:MainThread (queued=0) [S]> )>
<write[ee1c155f-d2de-4f09-b05d-5b5e6f4de1d6] ('SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2\r\n' )>
<connect[ee1c155f-d2de-4f09-b05d-5b5e6f4de1d6] ('127.0.0.1', 22 )>
<connected[ee1c155f-d2de-4f09-b05d-5b5e6f4de1d6] ('127.0.0.1', 22 )>
<_write[ee1c155f-d2de-4f09-b05d-5b5e6f4de1d6] (<socket._socketobject object at 0x100ff5830> )>
<_read[ee1c155f-d2de-4f09-b05d-5b5e6f4de1d6] (<socket._socketobject object at 0x100ff5830> )>
<read[ee1c155f-d2de-4f09-b05d-5b5e6f4de1d6] ('SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2\r\n' )>
<write[server] (<socket._socketobject object at 0x100ff5980>, 'SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2\r\n' )>
<_write[server] (<socket._socketobject object at 0x100ff5980> )>
<_read[server] (<socket._socketobject object at 0x100ff5980> )>
```

**Terminal 2 (client):**

```
Fri May 23 14:06:26
~
$ ssh -p 3333 localhost
Last login: Fri May 23 14:04:51 2014 from localhost

Fri May 23 14:06:31
~
$ logout
Connection to localhost closed.
```